# Implemetation of Ordered trait in scala

Tags: scala

I have implemented a scala class with ordered trait implemented..

```
class CDR_NOR(SUBSCRIBER_ID:String, CHARGING_ID:String, NODE_ID:String, val START_TIME:String) extends Ordered [CDR_NOR]
 {
    def compare(that: CDR_NOR) = {
if (this.START_TIME.matches("[\\d]{4}-[\\d]{2}-[\\d]{2}[\\s]{1}[\\d]{2}:[\\d]{2}:[\\d]{2}:[\\d]+") && that.START_TIME.matches("[\\d]{4}-[\\d]{2}-[\\d]{2}[\\s]{1}[\\d]{2}:[\\d]{2}:[\\d]{2}:[\\d]+")) {
    val formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:SSS")
    val d1 = formatter.parseDateTime(this.START_TIME)
    val d2 = formatter.parseDateTime(that.START_TIME)
    d1.compareTo(d2)
  }
  else
  0
 }
}

 case class DXE_NOR(SUBSCRIBER_ID:String, CHARGING_ID:String, NODE_ID:String,
               START_TIME:String, DXE_PROTOCOL_ID:String, DXE_SUB_PROTOCOL_ID:String, DXE_APPLICATION_ID:String, DXE_INTERNET_SERVER_IP:String,
               DXE_SENDER_ID: String, DXE_USAGE_TYPE: String, DXE_FILE_Population_TIME: String, DXE_IMSI: String, DXE_MSISDN: String, DXE_IMEI: String, DXE_CHARGING1_ID: String, DXE_UE_IP_ADDRESS: String,
               DXE_SESSION_ID: String, DXE_BEARER_CREATION_TIME: String, DXE_EVENT_START_TIME: String, DXE_EVENT_END_TIME: String, DXE_DURATION: String, DXE_UPLINK_VOL: String, DXE_DOWNLINK_VOL: String, DXE_TOTAL_VOL: String, DXE_RAT_TYPE: String,
               DXE_CELL_ID: String, DXE_ECELL_ID: String, DXE_HPMN: String, DXE_VPMN: String, DXE_SUBSCRIBER_TYPE: String, DXE_ROAM_TYPE: String, DXE_HANDSET_CATEGORY: String, DXE_GATEWAY_IP_ADDRESS: String,
               DXE_SERVING_IP_ADDRESS: String, DXE_APN: String, DXE_APN_TYPE: String, DXE_APP_NAME: String, DXE_DOMAIN_NAME: String,
               DXE_HTTP_PROXY_SERVER_IP_ADDRESS: String, DXE_PROXY_DOMAIN_NAME: String, DXE_CHARGING_CHARACTERISTICS: String, DXE_APN_RA_FLAG: String, DXE_APP_RA_FLAG: String, DXE_URL_RA_FLAG: String, DXE_Original_FILE_NAME: String
              ) extends CDR_NOR(SUBSCRIBER_ID,CHARGING_ID,NODE_ID,START_TIME)
```

In the second class I get Parametre START_TIME needs override modifier..

Comment: either make it a case class or add a val to START_TIME: `class CDR_NOR(SUBSCRIBER_ID:String, CHARGING_ID:String, NODE_ID:String, val START_TIME:String)`

Comment: If I make it as val then I have another class which is derived from my CDR_NOR..then in that class it gives me compilation error..what I should do for that class?

Comment: well, that depends on the 1) error, 2) the other class, doesn't it?

Comment: I edited my original question..

Comment: I see, So is CDR_NOR instantiated as is or are only the sub types used?

Comment: CDR_NOR is an abstract class..

Answer (score 2):

Well, if `CDR_NOR` is abstract you could define it as such:

```
abstract class CDR_NOR extends Ordered [CDR_NOR] {
  def SUBSCRIBER_ID:String
  def CHARGING_ID:String
  def NODE_ID:String
  def START_TIME:String

  def compare(that: CDR_NOR) = {
   if (this.START_TIME.matches("[\\d]{4}-[\\d]{2}-[\\d]{2}[\\s]{1}[\\d]{2}:[\\d]{2}:[\\d]{2}:[\\d]+") && 
       that.START_TIME.matches("[\\d]{4}-[\\d]{2}-[\\d]{2}[\\s]{1}[\\d]{2}:[\\d]{2}:[\\d]{2}:[\\d]+")) {

      val formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:SSS")
      val d1 = formatter.parseDateTime(this.START_TIME)
      val d2 = formatter.parseDateTime(that.START_TIME)

      d1.compareTo(d2)
    } else {
      0
    }
  }
}

case class DXE_NOR(SUBSCRIBER_ID:String, CHARGING_ID:String, NODE_ID:String,
               START_TIME:String, DXE_PROTOCOL_ID:String, DXE_SUB_PROTOCOL_ID:String, DXE_APPLICATION_ID:String, DXE_INTERNET_SERVER_IP:String,
               DXE_SENDER_ID: String, DXE_USAGE_TYPE: String, DXE_FILE_Population_TIME: String, DXE_IMSI: String, DXE_MSISDN: String, DXE_IMEI: String, DXE_CHARGING1_ID: String, DXE_UE_IP_ADDRESS: String,
               DXE_SESSION_ID: String, DXE_BEARER_CREATION_TIME: String, DXE_EVENT_START_TIME: String, DXE_EVENT_END_TIME: String, DXE_DURATION: String, DXE_UPLINK_VOL: String, DXE_DOWNLINK_VOL: String, DXE_TOTAL_VOL: String, DXE_RAT_TYPE: String,
               DXE_CELL_ID: String, DXE_ECELL_ID: String, DXE_HPMN: String, DXE_VPMN: String, DXE_SUBSCRIBER_TYPE: String, DXE_ROAM_TYPE: String, DXE_HANDSET_CATEGORY: String, DXE_GATEWAY_IP_ADDRESS: String,
               DXE_SERVING_IP_ADDRESS: String, DXE_APN: String, DXE_APN_TYPE: String, DXE_APP_NAME: String, DXE_DOMAIN_NAME: String,
               DXE_HTTP_PROXY_SERVER_IP_ADDRESS: String, DXE_PROXY_DOMAIN_NAME: String, DXE_CHARGING_CHARACTERISTICS: String, DXE_APN_RA_FLAG: String, DXE_APP_RA_FLAG: String, DXE_URL_RA_FLAG: String, DXE_Original_FILE_NAME: String
              ) extends CDR_NOR
```

**UPDATE**
However, afaik it is commonly recommended to prefer `Ordering`above `Ordered`:

```
abstract class CDR_NOR {
  def SUBSCRIBER_ID: String

  def CHARGING_ID: String

  def NODE_ID: String

  def START_TIME: String
}

object CDR_NOR {
  implicit object CdrOrdering extends Ordering[CDR_NOR] {
    def compare(x: CDR_NOR, y: CDR_NOR): Int = {
      if (x.START_TIME.matches("[\\d]{4}-[\\d]{2}-[\\d]{2}[\\s]{1}[\\d]{2}:[\\d]{2}:[\\d]{2}:[\\d]+") &&
        y.START_TIME.matches("[\\d]{4}-[\\d]{2}-[\\d]{2}[\\s]{1}[\\d]{2}:[\\d]{2}:[\\d]{2}:[\\d]+")) {

        val formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:SSS")
        val d1 = formatter.parseDateTime(x.START_TIME)
        val d2 = formatter.parseDateTime(y.START_TIME)

        d1.compareTo(d2)
      } else {
        0
      }
    }
  }
}
```

For `sorted` you would have to make sure, that the `implicit Ordering` is in scope. And to use operators you would have to import `Ordering.Implicits._`

Comment: Hi thanks it resolved my problem...val cdrs=new ArrayBuffer[DXE_NOR]()

          val d1=new DXE_NOR("Invalid DXE Probe","", ..) val d2=new DXE()
          cdrs+=(d1)
          cdrs+=(d2)
          cdrs.sorted.foreach(println)..but I get not enough arguments for method sorted..how to call sorted?

Comment: @user2021147 Thats probably one of the main reasons most people use the `Ordering` trait instead. sorted expects an implicit ordering. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Hi If I update my code to the second one using CdrOrdering then I can't instatiate the child classes derived from CDR_NOR such as DXE_NOR..can you give me any solution?

Comment: @user2021147 Uhm, why not? Is there an error message?

Comment: Hi, I can can instantiate them but when I wanna sort them "println(x._1 + " "+ x._2.toArray[CDR_NOR].sorted".. I get below message..Error:(498, 53) No implicit Ordering defined for CDR_NOR...
          
                                                    ^

Comment: @user2021147 In this case the compiler does not seem to look for the implicit ordering in the `CDR_NOR` companion object. Try to pull it into scope by e.g. `import CDR_NOR.CdrOrdering`.